# Can't install dada2. Used to work fine

Tags: r, package, installation

I was using dada2 perfectly fine a month ago on 2 computers. But now everytime I want to load the dada2 package it gives me this error message on both computers. I am using windows. I have seen someone post similar questions for other package but none of the solutions works. It's not a Rcpp problem as I have tried that.

I also reinstall R and have tried every method to install dada2 like from a source, from local file, and from the packages tab from R etc., but none of them work. The other packages such as ggplot2 are working fine so it feels like a dada2 specific problem. Can anyone help please?

The dada2 package is unpacked sucessfully. Then when I load it using library("dada2") it gives error message as below:

```
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dada2’
```

Comment: Is that the complete error message? I would normally expect that error to be associated with a missing package, the name of which would be listed. Also I believe that `dada2` should be installed using `biocLite()`.

Comment: The package is installed. It just can not be load. I can see it from the package tab in Rgui. When I try to load it it gives me error message.

Comment: It did associated with some missing packages. I load the indicated packages one by one then stuck in this matrixStats now. , R 3.4.0 (2017-04-21).
Installing package(s) ‘matrixStats’
Error in if (file.exists(dest) && file.mtime(dest) > file.mtime(lib) &&  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed           does that mean if I can't install this matrixStats then I won't be able to load dada2? How do I solve this error?

Comment: I've seen that error when upgrading R version, but that may not be the only cause. It is difficult to troubleshoot other people's systems in cases like this. All I can really recommend is to reinstall R 3.4.0 (and RStudio), then start again with fresh package installs.